# Unwanted arrowhead at the end of a tikz underbracket

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, brackets, automata

I'm trying to reproduce this automata:
[image]

This is what I have managed to achieve, so far:
[image]

And here's my MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,scale = 1,transform shape,bend angle=10,accepting/.style={double distance=2pt, outer sep=0.75pt+\pgflinewidth}]

    \node[state,initial] (p_0) {$p_0$};
    \node[state] (p_1) [right of=p_0] {$p_1$};
    \node[state] (p_2) [right of=p_1] {$p_2$};
    \node (p_3) [right of=p_2] {$\dots$};
    \node[state] (p_k) [right of=p_3] {$p_k$};
    
    \path (p_0) edge              node {$0$} (p_1)
        (p_1) edge              node {$0$} (p_2)
        (p_2) edge              node {$0$} (p_3)
        (p_3) edge              node {$0$} (p_k);
        \draw[decorate,thick, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt,mirror}] (p_0.south) -- (p_k.south)
          node [midway,below=10pt] {$k+1$};
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{document}
```

The problem is that with my code I get an arrowhead at the end of the underbrace (unwanted).
I did a test, and I understood that this is due to the `->` inside the `\begin{tikzpicture}`'s brackets.
Is there anyone that has some hints for me? Thanks!

Comment: When you write `\begin{tikzpicture}[->]`, all the paths (including the braces) in the tikzpicture will be drawn with an arrow. That's the issue. See the answer below where `[->]` has been moved to the path inside the picture and not in the general declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `->` from the options of the `tikzpicture` to the `options` of the relevant path. Also, use `positioning` (or possibly `chains`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,scale = 1,transform shape,bend angle=10,accepting/.style={double distance=2pt, outer sep=0.75pt+\pgflinewidth}]

    \node[state,initial] (p_0) {$p_0$};
    \node[state] (p_1) [right=of p_0] {$p_1$};
    \node[state] (p_2) [right=of p_1] {$p_2$};
    \node (p_3) [right=of p_2] {$\dots$};
    \node[state] (p_k) [right=of p_3] {$p_k$};
    
    \path[->] (p_0) edge              node {$0$} (p_1)
        (p_1) edge              node {$0$} (p_2)
        (p_2) edge              node {$0$} (p_3)
        (p_3) edge              node {$0$} (p_k);
    \draw[decorate,thick, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt,mirror}] (p_0.south) -- (p_k.south)
          node [midway,below=10pt] {$k+1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It was easier than I thought, thanks a lot!